# Is this a bad use of a `yield` statement?

Tags: python, yield

I was taking a look at the code of a coworker and I felt like this was an unnecessary use of the `yield` statement. It was something like this:

```py
def standardize_text(text: str):
    pattern = r"ABC" # some regex
    yield re.sub(pattern, "X", text)

def preprocess_docs(docs: List[str]):
    for doc in docs:
        yield standardize_text(doc)
```

I understand the use of `yield` in `preprocess_docs` so that I can return a generator, which would be helpful if `docs` is a large list. But I don't understand the value of the `yield` in the `standardize_text` function. To me, a `return` statement would do the exact same thing.

Is there a reason why that `yield` would be useful?

Comment: I think you are right - I can't see the benefit of doing a single yield of a string.

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't just ask your coworker... (for the record, I don't see a good reason, but I'm no expert on Python generators)

Comment: `return` wouldn't do the same thing, it would make `preprocess_docs` a simple generator of values, rather than a generator of (single element) generators. I can't imagine *why* you'd want that, but there is a difference. Changing `preprocess_docs` to use `yield from` instead of `yield` would have the same effect (though it would almost certainly be slower than `return` with plain `yield`).

Comment: Yeah, not useful.  Also, if you're going to annotate your parameters, you should annotate your return type.  If your coworker had type annotated this code (using mypy to make sure the annotation was correct) they would probably have realized on their own that returning a `Generator[Generator[str]]` wasn't actually what they wanted to do.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do

Comment: If this is a standalone function, then your coworker is confused. The only rational explanation is that  `standardize_text` is getting passed to some pre-existing API that *requires* a generator (and, perhaps, the fact that his particular use case only generates one value is incidental).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To me, a `return` statement would do the exact same thing.

**Using `return` instead wouldn't be the same as `yield`**, as explained in [ShadowRanger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146915/is-this-a-bad-use-of-pythons-yield-statement#comment120443303_68146915).

With `yield`, calling the function gives you a [**generator object**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
>>> standardize_text("ABCD")
<generator object standardize_text at 0x10561f740>
```

Generators can produce more than one result (unlike functions that use `return`). This generator *happens* to produce exactly one item, which is a string (the result of `re.sub`). You can collect the generator's results into a `list()`, for example, or just grab the first result with `next()`:

```
>>> list(standardize_text("ABCD"))
['XD']

>>> g = standardize_text("ABCD")
>>> next(g)
'XD'
>>> next(g) # raises StopIteration, indicating the generator has finished
```

If we change the function to use `return`:

```
def standardize_text(text: str):
    pattern = r"ABC" # some regex
    return re.sub(pattern, "X", text)
```

Then calling the function just gives us the **single result only** — no `list()` or `next()` needed.

```
>>> standardize_text("ABCD")
'XD'
```

---

> Is there a reason why that `yield` would be useful?

In the `standardize_text` function, no, not really. But your `preprocess_docs` function actually does make use of returning more than one value with `yield`: it returns a generator with one result for each of the values in `docs`. Those results are either generators themselves (in your original code with `yield`) or strings (if we change `standardize_text` to use `return`).

```
def preprocess_docs(docs: List[str]):
    for doc in docs:
        yield standardize_text(doc)

# returns a generator because the implementation uses "yield"
>>> preprocess_docs(["ABCD", "AAABC"])
<generator object preprocess_docs at 0x10561f820>

# with standardize_text using "yield re.sub..."
>>> for x in preprocess_docs(["ABCD", "AAABC"]): print(x)
... 
<generator object standardize_text at 0x1056cce40>
<generator object standardize_text at 0x1056cceb0>


# with standardize_text using "return re.sub..."
>>> for x in preprocess_docs(["ABCD", "AAABC"]): print(x)
... 
XD
AAX
```

Note: Prior to Python 3's `async`/`await`, some concurrency libraries used `yield` in the same way that `await` is now used. For example, [Twisted's `@inlineCallbacks`](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/twisted-17.9.0/core/howto/defer-intro.html#inline-callbacks-using-yield). I don't think this is directly relevant to your question, but I included it for completeness.